# Classify the fixed point at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Classify the fixed point at the origin for the following system for all real values of the parameter $a$.

$\dot{x}=-y+ax^3$

$\dot{y}=x+ay^3$

The Jacobian of this system incorrectly predicts that the origin is a center; it is actually a spiral if you plot the phase plane for $a\ne0$. Presumably we use polar coordinates to classify the fixed point, but how?

Comment: Remark: not "incorrectly predicts", but "can't be used in this situation"

Comment: To elaborate: whenever linear theory predicts a center, nonlinear terms may say otherwise. This is not the case with sinks, sources or saddles: these are said to be *structurally stable* because they retain their nature even when nonlinear terms are accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let

- $x = r \cos \theta$
- $y = r \sin \theta$
- $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \rightarrow x x' + y y' = r r'$

Substitute and solve for $r'$ and $\theta'$

Comment: Needs a TU! + 1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get $\dot{r}=ar^3(cos^4\theta+sin^4\theta)$. Does this look right? To work out $\dot{\theta}$ should I use $\theta=arctan(y/x)$? This gives me a messy answer.

Comment: I thought $\theta' = 1$ after simplification.

Comment: How do you get this?

Comment: You can derive this equation $\theta' = \dfrac{x y' - y x'}{r^2}$. Substitute and simplify. If you look at $a = -1, a = 0 , a = 1$ and the equations for $r'$ and $\theta'$, you see what is happening and that is the point of the exercise. You can also simplufy $r'$ to make it much cleaner. Regards

Comment: I'm still not getting $\theta'=1$ and unable to simplify $r'$ further. I feel like I'm missing something here? I've been able to use polar coordinates with other systems fine.

Comment: $\displaystyle \theta' = \frac{xy'-yx'}{r^2} = \frac{x(x + ay^3)-y(-y+ax^3)}{r^2} = \frac{x^2+y^2+axy^3-axy^3}{r^2} = \frac{r^2}{r^2} = 1$. Got it? Also, you can solve for $\theta$ in one of the two formulas above to find the expression I used.

Comment: @Amzoti Actually, when you do the multiplication, you get $\frac{x^2+y^2+axy^3-ayx^3}{r^2}$. I am having similar difficulties with using Polar Coordinates here.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first equation by $x$, the second by $y$ and add the two resulting equations.